# access denied for specific image in post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

The Social Media Department would like a directory where they can upload images and other media that need to be kept private until we are ready to publish them. Ideally, we would want the user to get a 404 error instead of being prompted to log in or instead of getting an "access denied" message if they put in an URL for a private file.

Because the Social Media Department does not want to have to move images once an article is ready to be published, really what they need is a way for images that are saved to the WordPress Media Library or some other folder to return a 404 error if they are part of articles that are not published and display for anyone if they are part of articles that art published.

Our users like to try and guess what we'll be announcing by putting in random image file names once they know the URL structure for the images

Comment: I don't suppose appending a 6 digit random number to the image file name would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

the only way is to track what you want or dont want or both. at some point you have to ask can this file be served. not hard to code but could be an expensive operation per request.

Answer (score 0):

To keep users from guessing names, you can either prepend/append a random string (per Graham Walters) or hash the whole name. Don't forget to suppress autoindexing of the directory via the Options .htaccess command, or a "Nothing to see here folks, move along." index.html file.

If users can somehow get hold of the names (say, via a leak), but there aren't too many "embargoed" files, the embargoed files could be added to an .htaccess blacklist similar to hotlink protection. Return a 404 if anyone requests those files not via your official pages. Remove them from the blacklist once they go live. If you set up the hotlink protection correctly, you may be able to forbid access to whole classes of files (such as by filetype), except for your official pages.